# How to structure lambda code for testability

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I am trying to make a small REST API with API gateway, lambda, and DynamoDB, while following good development practices such as TDD. I'm used to being able to use a DI container to provision my objects, which lends itself perfectly for mocking and testing. In an MVC framework, there would be a single entry point, where I could define my container configuration, bootstrap the application, and invoke the controller to handle the event. I could test the controller independently of the rest of the application, and inject mocked dependencies. I can't figure out how to decouple the dependencies a lambda function may have from the lambda function itself. For example:

```
const { DynamoDB } = require('aws-sdk')
const { UserRepo } = require('../lib/user-repo')

const client   = new DynamoDB({ region: process.env.REGION }) // Should be resolved by DI container
const userRepo = new UserRepo(client) // Should be resolved by DI container

exports.handler = async (event) => {
  return userRepo.get(event.id)
}
```

Please can anyone lead me in the right direction for structuring lambda code so it can be unit tested properly?

Answer (score 3):

One way we've approached this in the project I'm currently working on is splitting out the requirements, so the `handler` is responsible for:

- Creating the clients;
- Extracting any config from the environment; and
- Getting the parameters from the event.

Then it calls another function that does most of the work, and which we can test in isolation. Think of the `handler` like a controller, and the other function like the service that does the work.

In your specific case, that might look like:

```js
const { DynamoDB } = require('aws-sdk');
const { UserRepo } = require('../lib/user-repo');

const doTheWork = (repo, id) => repo.get(id);

exports.handler = async (event) => {
  const client = new DynamoDB({ region: process.env.REGION });
  const userRepo = new UserRepo(client); 
  return doTheWork(userRepo, event.id);
}
```

`doTheWork` can now be exercised at the unit level using test doubles for the repo object and whatever inputs you want. The `UserRepo` is already decoupled by constructor injection of the Dynamo client, so that should be pretty testable too.

We also have tests at the integration level that *only* mock out the AWS SDK stuff (you could alternatively use transport layer mocking or something like [`aws-sdk-mock`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/aws-sdk-mock)) plus E2E testing that ensures the whole system works together.

Comment: Okay so basically the lambda function should be so simple that it doesn't need unit testing itself, and could perhaps be covered by integration tests instead?

Comment: @BenGuest that's the model we've gone for, yes.